# Django 2.1 creates autotable

Tags: python, django, migration, create-table, migrate

I'm pretty new at Django 2.1 framework.
and I am a week trying to setup the tables for my app. Settings are fine I listed my app in INSTALLED_APPS, but when I try to run manage.py migrate code it gives me one auto_table instead of the ones that was written on model file.

These are my models.

**`Models.py`**

```
from django.db import models


class Nome (models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100),
    objetivo = models.CharField(max_length=100),


class Sobrenome (models.Model):
    lets = models.ForeignKey(Nome, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
    make = models.CharField(max_length=100),
```

That's what migrate code gave to me:

```
from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

initial = True

dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Dreams',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Wish',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
        ],
    ),
]
```

Comment: Add setting file and DB settings

Comment: Did you run `manage.py makemigrations` before `migrate`?

Comment: yes i did and gaves me only the auto tables
i ll put the settings file now

Comment: Lucas did you run `makemigrations appname`?

Comment: `
'ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'webdeve',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
`

Comment: i did and this is my first time asking on stack, sorry for the mistakes i really aprecciate the attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have ended each line in your models definitions with a comma. This makes each attribute a tuple, so it is not recognized as an actual field. Remove the commas:

```
class Nome (models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    objetivo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and run makemigrations again.

Comment: i took them out squashed my migrations and tried aggain. 
unfortunately it stills didn't create the tables